# Получение изображения из AWS S3 для использования на сайте. Java

Tags: java, heroku, fileupload, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Я разобрался как загружать файл в bucket aws s3, научился его скачивать в директорию на компьютере. Но не могу понять каким способом загружать файлы из AWS S3 непосредственно на сайт (сайт на Heroku),  не скачивая файлы на компьютер. Подскажите хотя бы в каком направлении двигаться.
java,maven,postgres,heroku,s3.

Вот код для скачивания файла в директорию на компьютере.

```
System.out.println("Downloading an object");
            S3Object s3object = s3client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(
                    bucketName, keyName));

            S3ObjectInputStream inputStream = s3object.getObjectContent();

            FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream, new File("/D:/IntellijIdea/test2.jpg"));
```

Comment: Вам надо картинки именно на сайт закачать? Или вам надо на сайте указать урлы картинок, которые на s3 лежат?

Comment: Не закачать на сайт, а отобразить на сайте. Получается что второе. Указать урлы для html тега

Comment: Тогда я не очень понял вашу проблему. Делайте вашим картинкам публичный доступ и указывайте их урл на своем сайте.